# Nginx "ssl_stapling" ignored, host not found in OCSP responder "ocsp.comodoca.com"

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to setup OCSP stapling on Nginx

I'm getting the error:

```
"ssl_stapling" ignored, host not found in OCSP responder "ocsp.comodoca.com"
```

Here's the file .conf

```
server {
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/myfile.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/myfile.key;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/myfile_trusted.crt;
    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 15s;
}
```

Please suggest a specific solution.

Comment: I have the same problem.  The OCSP responder cannot find ocsp.cloudflare.com/origin_ca

Answer (score 4):

I've just met the same issue when testing a new *nginx* config with `nginx -t` (**run as root**); in my case the error message was:

```
2014/11/15 01:38:43 [warn] 5114#0: "ssl_stapling" ignored, host not found in OCSP responder "ocsp.startssl.com/sub/class1/server/ca"
```

However, I renewed my trial a second time a few seconds later and then it worked.

My advice are the following:

- check that the configured resolver is responding (but I believe you used Google Public DNS so they should be okay);
- try to remove the extraneous options (second resolver address, `valid=` parameter and `resolver_timeout` directive);
- check that your `ssl_trusted_certificate` file is a bundle of both root CA certificate and intermediate certificate **in PEM format** (in my case I appended the Class 1 Intermediate Server CA to the root CA with `# cat ca.pem sub.class1.server.ca.pem > bundle_certs.pem`).

I just noticed your `ssl_trusted_certificate` file ends with `.crt`. I'm not sure whether this is really relevant but [nginx documentation says](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_trusted_certificate) (emphasis mine):

> Syntax:   `ssl_trusted_certificate` *file*;
>   Default:  —
>   Context:  `http, server`
>
> This directive appeared in version 1.3.7.
>
> Specifies a *file* with trusted CA certificates **in the PEM format** used to verify client certificates and OCSP responses if ssl_stapling is enabled.

So you may want to check this first.

If it may help my OCSP config is:

```
# OCSP Stapling ---
# fetch OCSP records from URL in ssl_certificate and cache them
# see <http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_stapling>
ssl_stapling on;
resolver 192.168.1.254;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
# verify chain of trust of OCSP response using Root CA and Intermediate certs
ssl_trusted_certificate https/bundle_certs.pem;
```

**Edit**: `192.168.1.254` being my home router LAN IP. Each time I test *nginx* config I get the same error the first time, I guess the resolver has to be initialized or something in the like.

Comment: See also the [PEM wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail#Format): 'PEM data is commonly stored in files with a ".pem" suffix, a ".cer" or ".crt" suffix (for certificates), or a ".key" suffix' For example, on Fedora there is `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` which points to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem`.